# "The meeting had been over by five o'clock"

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs, past-perfect

There is the sentence from an Android English studying app:

> The meeting had been over by five o'clock.

But I was told that this sentence is wrong. The correct sentences are

> - The meeting had finished by five o’clock.
> - The meeting was over by five o'clock.

So I can't understand why we can't just replace "finished" with "been over" in the sentence "The meeting had finished by five o’clock"?

Comment: I would expect _had been over_ to be followed by a time period rather than an exact time - "The meeting had been over for an hour when..."

Comment: Thank you. So, "The meeting had been over by five o'clock." is completly incorrect, right?
I would like to clarify: is the part "meeting had been over" considered here
1. as the passive part "meeting had been" (as in sentence "The work had been finished ...") + adjective "over",
2. or as the active part "meeting had"(as in sentence "The meeting had finished ...") + composite verb "been over" ?

Comment: It's incorrect as a statement on its own. It could be part of a longer sentence, such as "If the meeting had been over by five o'clock I would probably have managed to catch the bus".